# Need help in proving an inequality related to logarithms

Tags: real-analysis, number-theory, summation, analytic-number-theory

I am self studying analytic number theory from class notes of a senior and in it I am unable to deduce an inequality which is not proved .

> Assume $b(m) = \sum_{s, t} \frac{1} {log(s) log(t) } $with these 3 conditions:

1. $2\leq s \leq n$
2. $2\leq t \leq n$
3. $s+t= m $

It is to be proved that if $m \leq n$, then $b(m) \geq (m-3) log^{-2} n $

Please help.

Comment: If $m\le n$, then $n$ should not play any role.

Comment: @user can you please write an answer which is a bit more ellaborated . I am confused.

Comment: It is not an answer but a comment aimed on improvement of your question. Do you see that if $n\ge m$, it can be replaced with $m-2$?

Comment: @user m -2 is not greater than Or equal to m. So, how can you replace it?

Comment: @user also why do you want to " improve the question " ? Do you mean giving a hint for proof?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $n\ge m$ the sum consists of $m-3$ terms. Since $\log x$ for $x\ge2$ is positive increasing function 
$$ \frac1{\log s \log (m-s)}>\frac1{\log^2 m}.$$

Therefore:
$$b(m)>\frac{m-3}{\log^2m}\ge\frac{m-3}{\log^2n}.$$